# Bomb lab phase_2

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

If I could get an expiation on how I can get the numbers it would really help. I have been working on this for 3 days.
Dump of assembler code for function phase_2:

```
   push   %rbp
   push   %rbx
   sub    $0x28,%rsp // 40 bytes of locals
   mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   mov    %rax,0x18(%rsp)
   xor    %eax,%eax
   mov    %rsp,%rsi
   callq  0x55555555704a <read_six_numbers>     // 6 numbers in a loop
   cmpl   $0x0,(%rsp)
   jne    0x5555555567ef <phase_2+43>
   cmpl   $0x1,0x4(%rsp)            // first real value is 1
   je     0x5555555567f4 <phase_2+48>
   callq  0x55555555700e <explode_bomb> // first bomb explosion
   mov    %rsp,%rbx         // points to the first number =1.
   lea    0x10(%rbx),%rbp           //0x10 = 16 = 5th element?
   jmp    0x555555556806 <phase_2+66> // jumps to line 66
   add    $0x4,%rbx                     // 4 moved to rbx?
   cmp    %rbp,%rbx
   je     0x555555556817 <phase_2+83>
   mov    0x4(%rbx),%eax                // 4 moved to eax?
   add    (%rbx),%eax
   cmp    %eax,0x8(%rbx)
   je     0x5555555567fd <phase_2+57>
   callq  0x55555555700e <explode_bomb>
   jmp    0x5555555567fd <phase_2+57> // jumps to line 57
   mov    0x18(%rsp),%rax
   xor    %fs:0x28,%rax
   jne    0x55555555682e <phase_2+106>
   add    $0x28,%rsp
   pop    %rbx
   pop    %rbp
   retq
   callq  0x555555556390 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
```

Comment: `add    $0x4,%rbx  // 4 moved to rbx` - that's an `add` not a `mov`. `mov    0x4(%rbx),%eax // 4 moved to eax?` - that's indirect addressing. The rest is fine. You should focus on the `cmp  %eax,0x8(%rbx)` and the instructions before it.

Comment: Please post your Assembly with offset information. As your information is incomplete, for example `jne    0x5555555567ef <phase_2+43>`, it is not obvious where to jump. If you provide the offset information, it will help other to help you too. Though, it is possible to figure it out based on the size of each instruction.

Comment: Also, post other related functions like `read_six_numbers` and `explode_bomb`.